# How to use ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT with a .cube file?

Tags: java, android, renderscript

first, I'm new to image processing in Android.  I have a .cube file that was "Generated by Resolve" that is LUT_3D_SIZE 33.  I'm trying to use android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT to apply the lookup table to process an image.  I assume that I should use ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT and NOT [android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicLUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicLUT.html), correct?

I'm having problems finding sample code to do this so this is what I've pieced together so far.  The issue I'm having is how to create an Allocation based on my .cube file?

```
...
final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());
final ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT scriptIntrinsic3DLUT = ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));

// How to create an Allocation from .cube file?
//final Allocation allocationLut = Allocation.createXXX();

scriptIntrinsic3DLUT.setLUT(allocationLut);

Bitmap bitmapIn = selectedImage;
Bitmap bitmapOut = selectedImage.copy(bitmapIn.getConfig(),true);

Allocation aIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmapIn);
Allocation aOut = Allocation.createTyped(renderScript, aIn.getType());

aOut.copyTo(bitmapOut);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapOut);
...
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

### Parsing the .cube file

First, what you should do is to parse the *.cube* file.
 [OpenColorIO](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenColorIO) shows how to do this in C++. It has some ways to parse the LUT files like *.cube*, *.lut*, etc.
For example, [FileFormatIridasCube.cpp](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenColorIO/blob/master/src/core/FileFormatIridasCube.cpp) shows how to 
process a *.cube* file.

You can easily get the size through 
 **LUT_3D_SIZE**. I have contacted an image processing algorithm engineer.
This is what he said:

- Generally in the industry a 17^3 cube is considered preview, 33^3 normal and 65^3 for highest quality output.

Note that in a *.cube* file, we can get **3*LUT_3D_SIZE^3** floats.
The key point is what to do with the float array. We cannot set this array to the cube in *ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT* with the *Allocation*.
Before doing this we need to handle the float array.

### Handle the data in .cube file

As we know, each RGB component is an 8-bit int if it is 8-bit depth.
R is in the high 8-bit, G is in the middle, and B is in the low 8-bit. In this way, a 24-bit int can contain these
three components at the same time.

In a .cube file, each data line contains 3 floats.
**Please note: the blue component goes first!!!**

I get this conclusion from trial and error. (Or someone can give a more accurate explanation.)

Each float represents the coefficient of the component according to 255. Therefore, we need to calculate the real
 value with these three components:

```
int getRGBColorValue(float b, float g, float r) {
    int bcol = (int) (255 * clamp(b, 0.f, 1.f));
    int gcol = (int) (255 * clamp(g, 0.f, 1.f));
    int rcol = (int) (255 * clamp(r, 0.f, 1.f));
    return bcol | (gcol << 8) | (rcol << 16);
}
```

So we can get an integer from each data line, which contains 3 floats.
And finally, we get the integer array, the length of which is **LUT_3D_SIZE^3**. This array is expected to be 
applied to the cube.

### ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT

[RsLutDemo](https://github.com/RenderScript/RsLutDemo) shows how to apply *ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT*.

```
RenderScript mRs;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Bitmap mLutBitmap;
ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT mScriptlut;
Bitmap mOutputBitmap;
Allocation mAllocIn;
Allocation mAllocOut;
Allocation mAllocCube;
...
int redDim, greenDim, blueDim;
int[] lut;
if (mScriptlut == null) {
    mScriptlut = ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT.create(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));
}
if (mBitmap == null) {
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.bugs);

    mOutputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());

    mAllocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mBitmap);
    mAllocOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mOutputBitmap);
}
...
// get the expected lut[] from .cube file.
...
Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));
tb.setX(redDim).setY(greenDim).setZ(blueDim);
Type t = tb.create();
mAllocCube = Allocation.createTyped(mRs, t);
mAllocCube.copyFromUnchecked(lut);

mScriptlut.setLUT(mAllocCube);
mScriptlut.forEach(mAllocIn, mAllocOut);

mAllocOut.copyTo(mOutputBitmap);
```

### Demo

I have finished a demo to show the work.
You can view it on [Github](https://github.com/Vensent/RsLutDemo).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a 3D LUT yes, you have to use the core framework version as there is no support library version of 3D LUT at this time.  Your 3D LUT allocation would have to be created by parsing the file appropriately, there is no built in support for .cube files (or any other 3D LUT format).

Comment: Ok, so don't use the android.support.v8 library and use core instead, i.e. android.renderscript.  Any resources on how to parse the .cube text file?  I've tried passing Allocation.createFromString() a string representation of the file but that didn't work.

android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: LUT must be 3d.

Comment: Correct, the core is the only thing which has support for 3DLUT.  That being said, the support library is where the active development (bugfixes, etc.) occurs, so it's a bit of a judgement call there on which to use.  You may encounter other problems if you're not using the support library.  AFAIK there's not built-in support for parsing the cube file or any other 3DLUT format.

Comment: I don't know why the docs started to say that active development happens only in support lib, but that is totally false--I've been spending way more time on android.renderscript.* than android.support.v8.renderscript.* lately. We actively develop both, and the support lib trails the platform version in terms of feature set but provides compatibility over more devices.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @tim-murray! I did think it strange the docs stated that since I've seen movement in the AOSP sources in both.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time finding examples of ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT, can anyone help?  I'm trying to figure out the parsing of the .cube file.

Comment: hey @TimMurray I'm really really sorry to hijack your comment like this, but would u mind checking my Renderscript question that is very related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401503/how-to-allocate-the-lut-to-use-on-scriptintrinsic3dlut ?